# unable to upload image along with field name insertion in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, image-upload

I am having problem for inserting filename all other fields are inserting correctly using codigniter following is the snippets my core problem is that how to add file name to array_from_post() to insert into database

page controller

```
public function edit($id = NULL) {
        //Fetch a page or set new one
        if ($id) {
            $this->data['page'] = $this->page_m->get($id);
            count($this->data['page']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'Page Could not be found';
        } else {
            $this->data['page'] = $this->page_m->get_new();
        }
        $id == NULL || $this->data['page'] = $this->page_m->get($id);
       //Pages for dropdown
       $this->data['pages_no_parents'] = $this->page_m->get_no_parents();
       //dump($this->data['pages_no_parents']);
        //Setup form

        $rules = $this->page_m->rules;

        $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
        //Process the form
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
            $data= $this->uploadimage();
            //dump($data);
            $data = $this->page_m->array_from_post(array(
                'title',
                'slug',
                'order',
                'body',
                'template',
                'parent_id',
                'filename'
                ));
            $this->page_m->save($data, $id);
            redirect('admin/page');
        }
        //Load the view    
        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/page/edit';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);

    }
```

image upload function in page controller

```
 public function uploadImage()
{
    $config['upload_path']      = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size']     = '100';
    $config['max_width']        = '1024';
    $config['max_height']       = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);        

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $data = $this->upload->data();

        return $data;
    }       

}
```

Model page_m

```
public function get_new() {
        $page = new stdClass();
        $page->title = '';
        $page->slug = '';
        $page->order = '';
        $page->body = '';
        $page->parent_id = 0;
        $page->template= 'page';
        $page->filename = '';
        return $page;
    }

function array_from_post from My_Model extending CI_Model

 public function array_from_post($fields){
        $data = array();
        foreach ($fields as $field){
            $data[$field] = $this->input->post($field);
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

and here is the code snippet from view

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/page/edit'); ?>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>Image</td>
        <td><?php echo form_upload($page->filename);?>></td>
    </tr>
```

I've database table with name "pages" and field name "filename" following the above code its just inserting "0" please advice

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
 public function uploadImage()
{
    $config['upload_path']      = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size']     = '100';
    $config['max_width']        = '1024';
    $config['max_height']       = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);        

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file'))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $data = $this->upload->data();

        return $data;
    }       

}
```